# Install PyEnv in Vagrantfile

Tags: python, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision, pyenv

PyEnv does not have a [great installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer), and it requires some post-install processing to get it to work correctly (such as modifying `.bashrc` to add to `$PATH` and make two `pyenv` calls). I'm wondering how anyone has been able to get PyEnv installed via Vagrantfile. I want to build a reusable image to develop on so that I don't have to go through the reinstall process if I destroy this VM.

I've tried running the installer and making the recommended edits to `.bashrc` to get `pyenv` working, but when I get into my Vagrant box `pyenv` is not installed. I've tried moving the `pyenv` script into `/bin/pyenv` but it is not there when the machine comes up. How do I make this work?

For reference, here is the script I'm currently running that fails to install PyEnv to a Vagrant machine during a Vagrant provision step in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# REQUIRES: curl, git

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-
installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash

cat >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc << 'EOF'

export PATH="$PATH:~/.pyenv/bin"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

EOF

exec $SHELL
```

And trying to move `pyenv` under `/bin`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# REQUIRES: curl, git

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
mv ~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv /bin/pyenv

cat >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc << 'EOF'

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

EOF

exec $SHELL
```

Neither work. How do I get this installed?

Comment: Hey! Could you try without using installer and follow the steps detailed in: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation. 

Converting the install steps at that link to a bash script should be pretty straightforward. Can you try before I answer in full?

Comment: Will try tomorrow, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're running the script through Vagrant shell provisioning as root so the update is done for your root user.
When you ssh into the VM, you're logged in with your vagrant user so its not available.

When you need to change is in your Vagrantfile to run the script using `privileged` option

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "xxx", privileged: false
```